# virtuemart On check out

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, virtuemart

I want to do a query to my product custom field when you press checkout

```
    function plgVmConfirmedOrder ($cart, $order) {


    $plugin = JPluginHelper::getPlugin('vmcustom', 'mi_plg');
    $pluginParams = new JRegistry();
    $pluginParams->loadString($plugin->params);



    $order_bt       = $order['items'];
    $user_id        = $order_bt->virtuemart_user_id;
    $order_number   = $order_bt->virtuemart_order_item_id;

    $db=JFactory::getDbo();
```

this foreach is  when I get to enter the parameters I want
        //foreach ($atri as $key) {

```
        $q=$db->getQuery(true);

        $q->update('#__virtuemart_custom_plg_mi_plg_values');
        $q->set('state='.(int)$cero);
        $q->where('customsforall_value_id='.(int)$virtuemart_order_id);
        $db->setQuery($q);


            return false;
        }

    //}

    return true;


}
```

When you press checkout you delete the cart and the current prodcuts and its attributes  i must to enter in the order but i cant. help my please

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'll put the answer in case someone else needs it:

we need to add a private variable in the beginning of our class vmcustom plugin that variable and assign our array with our custom fields and then call that variable from our function

```
class plgVmCustomOurPlugin extends vmCustomPlugin {
   private $values_root;

    function plgVmOnViewCart(){

    $this->values_root = $values;
   }
   function plgVmConfirmedOrder{

    $values =  $this->values_root;


   }


}
```